# Print string one word at a time in textbox (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a user on my application enter a paragraph or whatever in a textbox and have an output on a label display one word at a time at a specific interval, for example if the textbox input was "This is a test message", the label would read "This", then after a few seconds, change to "is", etc

Thank you!

Comment: Any attempts to achieve that? Show some relevant code and you'll get many answers.

Comment: You also need to specify the UI platform (WPF, WInForms, ASP.Net etc.). TextBox and Label are quite common objects.

Comment: It is Winforms. I was thinking it may be possible to split each word of the textbox string into individual variables, but im not sure how to do that

Comment: `dim words = YourTextBox.Text.Split()`. It return an array of strings. Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, setting its `Interval` property as required and add a `words` part (plus a space) each time the Timer Ticks. You can use an Integer Field to store the current position of the `words` array. Increment the Field value on each the `Timer.Tick` event, untill you have read all the strings, after that, you can disable the Timer (in the `Tick` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) Add a TextBox, a button and a Label to the Form from the designer.

2) Make the form's code look like this.

```
'Create a timer
WithEvents TMR As New Timer
'And a counter
Dim count As Integer
Dim wordList As New List(Of String)

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    count = 0
    wordList.Clear()
    wordList.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Split(" "))
    TMR.Interval= 1000 '1 second
    TMR.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimerEventProcessor(myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles TMR.Tick
    Label1.Text = wordList(count)
    If count < wordList.Count
       count++
    Else
       count = 0
    End If
End Sub
```